# What kind of beer can I make with these ingredients?

Tags: beer, recipe

I have used most of these to make a Czech Pilsner, which came out every well, however, I don't have a refrigerator in which to lager the pilsner right now.  So, I'm looking for a light refreshing beer that will take me though the summer. I can get different hops if that would benefit the recipe. BTW this would be a 5 gallon partial-grain extract recipe. Thanks.

- Weyermann Carahell grain
- 6lbs of Pilsen light DME
- Saaz Hops (approx 3/4 pound)
- Citra 1/2 oz
- BRY-97
- Nottingham and Safale US-05 yeasts

Answer (score 5):

I answered this mostly as an exercise for myself since I may be in this situation and like fiddling with recipes. My brewing experience on a scale to 0 to 10 isn't 0 but not exactly 1 either.

For a 5 gal batch: 6lbs Pilsen DME and 1lbs (you didn't specify so I assumed just 1) will get you either a belgian blonde ale or an american ipa (although light on color) depending on how you hop it. Based on what you asked for I'd go with belgian blonde which will be less bitter and less hoppy than an ipa.

- 6lbs Pilsen DME
- 1lb CaraHell

Hop additions:

- 60 mins - 1 oz Saaz
- 15 mins - 0.25 oz Citra and 0.25 oz Saaz
- 5 mins - 0.25 oz Citra

Use Safale US-05 yeast

- OG 1.056
- FG 1.008
- IBU 21
- SRM 4
- ABV 6%

If it were me I wouldn't worry what type of beer it winds up being I'd say just brew it like you would have brewed the pilsner but ferment it with ale yeast at ale temperatures and see what happens.

Comment: Made the recipe today, went very well. Did a 4 gallon boil, added 1/2 tab of Whirlfloc @ 10 minutes, topped off to 5 gallons. Definitely looks blonde at this point, we'll see how it turns out in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Just to keep you up on this, has been fermenting like crazy for the past two days, moving along nicely.

Comment: @Quentin  As I said I have very little experience but I have been playing with various recipes. All I did was enter your fermentables in a recipe on brewtoad.com along with US-05 since I know a bit about it. Ran through the different styles to see which one yours matched fairly close to. BBA seemed the best fit. Then I searched other BBA recipes with your hops for ideas. I added 1/4 oz of Saaz to the 15 min addition to get ibu to the right range and add slightly more complexity to the flavor based mainly on reading descriptions. Will be on dry side. Hope it's good.

Comment: I'm sure it will be fine, still bubbling away nicely.  I'll keep you posted.  I will have to check out brewtoad.com, that information you provided is interesting.

Comment: If you have a hydrometer or refractometer if be interested in seeing how og and fg come out. I used a conservative efficiency of 65 so you may get higher og. And I don't think us05 had as much attenuation as betting says. Might not be as dry as I thought.

Comment: Fermentation slowed considerably after 4 days, today is day 6 and it registered 1.012, like you said, probably not as dry as you anticipated.  Unfortunately, I did not measure the OG, once I remembered a day passed. I'll check it tomorrow and see if it is stable.

Comment: Ok, FG has remained at 1.012, letting it clear and then we'll see how it did.

Comment: You brewed my first beer recipe before I did :) My second one has been fermenting since sunday morning. Just a simple single hopped amber DME to see if I can boil on my stove. My first beer I pretty much just pushed a button.

Comment: @Quentin any update?

Comment: Been away for a bit, beer is nice, light, too easy to drink more then one. Just did a ESB to back this one up.  Thanks again (not suppose to say that) ;)